# Adding a Like button to my web site

Tags: facebook-like

I've added a facebook Like button to a few of my web site pages. All of them work except for the home page and I can't figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to answer this question without seeing some sample code of your "home page".

Answer (score 0):

Check your page with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

If the response code isn't 200 or your meta tags don't appear properly or whatever else, at least you'll know where to look. Keep in mind that when you click like, Facebook makes a request to your page. Make sure you let Facebook do that (don't block/Redirect the Facebook crawler).

Edit: Sometimes, simply adding your URL and testing on the link above solves the problem. This is if you had a problem with the site when you first added it and meanwhile Facebook cached it as problematic. Debugging it will clear the Facebook cache for that URL.